# Serving local images with Play 2 to be displayed inline

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Earlier I asked how to serve a local image here: [Serving local images with Play 2 / Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131830/serving-local-images-with-play-2-scala)

This works well, except that the image is forced to download by the browser, instead of being displayed in the browser.

I have added "inline = true" argument to OK.sendFile, as described here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaStream , but that doesn't seem to work, the image is still being downloaded. It seems that Content Type is not getting recognized? Play documentation says it should automatically set it using the file extension, so not sure what's going. Help?

EDIT: Response header example:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Length:2694220

Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Comment: Paste all _Response header_ that incomes for this request (grab it within your browser with some inspection tool(

Comment: @biesior : 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Length:2694220

Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Answer (score 2):

Looking through Play's code, I realized I could simply add .withHeaders onto sendFile:

Ok.sendFile(content = new java.io.File("filepath"), inline = true).withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "image/jpeg")

This solved the problem! Thanks @biesior for the pointer.