# How to view images from local directories in play scala project

Tags: image, scala, file, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am newbie to `Play scala framework`,in my project I have a functionality of `uploading` a `image` and `showing` a uploaded image into `view` page.I have stored the `uploaded images` into my system's `local` folder and passed the images `path` into my `view` page,but it doesn't show the images. 
I have passed the image stored location `path` as `imagepath` and used the below code to view the image.

```
<img src=@routes.Assets.at(imagepath) class="responsive" >
```

**Note:** If I stored the images in `projectname/public/images` project `directory` the images are showing in view page. please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131830/serving-local-images-with-play-2-scala

Comment: @Thomas Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement an action yourself. As I answered in [Play Framework: Handling dynamic created files (images) in PRODUCTION mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205870/play-framework-handling-dynamic-created-files-images-in-production-mode/32217274#32217274)

Here's the steps
First in your routes file, add something like this:

```
GET /user/images/:name controllers.Application.imageAt(name:String)
```

And write a simple file reader in action imageAt which return the file in stream. Again my sample is in Java but you should archive the same using Scala

```
    File imageFile = new File(ReportFileHelper.getImagePath());
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
    //resource type such as image+png, image+jpg
        String resourceType = "image+"+imageName.substring(imageName.length()-3);
        return ok(new FileInputStream(imageFile)).as(resourceType);
    } else {
        return notFound(imageFile.getAbsoluteFile());
    }
```

After that, the images is reachable via revers router:

```
 <img src=@routes.Application.imageAt(imageName)>
```

Or directly via url

```
 <img src="/user/images/imageName">
```

Comment: Waterscar,`Thomas` and your answers both are same.Thanks